# UINavigationController cant set left button

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to add a custom `UIBarButton` to my `UINavigationBar`, it should be displayed in the left side.

When I try the button just wont show, but if I move it to the `rightBarButton` it displays.

Here is my code:

`ViewDidLoad()`:

```
UIBarButtonItem *menuItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Menu"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:[SlideNavigationController sharedInstance] action:@selector(toggleLeftMenu)];
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:menuItem];
```

Comment: Your code works for me. Must be something other than these two lines. Maybe you set another LeftBarButtonItem downstream without realizing.

Comment: may be because back button is automatically added left side

Comment: the leftBarButtons array of the navigationItem is null soo?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the bar button item like this:

```
UINavigationItem *navItem = self.navigationItem;
navItem.leftBarButtonItem = menuItem;
```

Comment: How would that help?  It ends up calling the exact same setter that OP is calling.